# What is the efficient way to save the result in Matlab if I have to stop the iteration for some reason?

Tags: performance, matlab, save

I am trying to minimize my objective function by running iterations and it could take a long time (may be a day or more). If for some reason I have to stop the program or it gets hung, what is the efficient way to save the results of the iterations that could have run till the time the program stops for some reason.

**The variables I want to save are:** `best_obj_fun` and `k_to_perturb_annealing_best`

**NOTE:** I am storing my `best_obj_fun` in matrix and I only want the value at the time of the last iteration for `k_to_perturb_annealing_best`

See the last loop in the following code for variables I want to have when the program is stopped somehow (e.g. CTRL+C):

```
%% Running iterations to find minimum objective function value

accept_iter=1;
for iter=1:100
    %# Choosing 'nRandomPoints' random points on the grid to sample from 'fixed_underlying_distribution'
    nRandomPoints=100;
    random_grid_points=randi(sqrt(nCell),[nRandomPoints,2]); %# two columns with x and y coord resp.
    repeated_set_of_coord=ismember(random_grid_points,fixed_grid_coordinates,'rows'); %# find repeated sets of coordinates

    while any(repeated_set_of_coord)
        random_grid_points(repeated_set_of_coord,:)=randi(sqrt(nCell),[sum(repeated_set_of_coord),2]); %# create new set of coordinates
        repeated_set_of_coord(repeated_set_of_coord)=ismember(random_grid_points(...
            repeated_set_of_coord,:),fixed_grid_coordinates,'rows'); %# check the new coordinates
    end
    linear_index_for_perturbation=sub2ind([sqrt(nCell),sqrt(nCell)],random_grid_points(:,1),...
        random_grid_points(:,2)); %# get a linear index into matrix to be perturbed
    k_to_perturb_annealing_initial=k_sisim_for_annealing;

    k_to_perturb_annealing_initial(linear_index_for_perturbation)=emprand(k_20_sampledata_sisim,nRandomPoints,1);

    %# computing the value of objective function for perturbed perm values
    [new_obj_fun,new_k_geomean]=obj_fun_for_gibbs_sampling(k_to_perturb_annealing_initial,x_200x200_gslib_format_vector...
        ,y_200x200_gslib_format_vector,gamma_k_underlying,mean_gamma_k_underlying,k_eff_WT);

    if  new_obj_fun < best_obj_fun(accept_iter)
        best_obj_fun(accept_iter+1)=new_obj_fun;
        k_to_perturb_annealing_best=k_to_perturb_annealing_initial;
        best_k_geomean=new_k_geomean;
        accept_iter=accept_iter+1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stop the iteration without closing matlab then an easy way to do this is to use the [assignin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/assignin.html) function inside your *for* loop. It lets you assign a value to a variable in your workspace, which means they will be there after you stop the iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `save` with the `-append` option inside the loop.

Assuming you have initialized your variables before the loop begins, you can create a file before the loop starts, and update it each time. Here's an example.

```
A=zeros(...);%# this is an example of your variables that are initialized before the loop
save('filename','A');%# this creates a .mat file with the initialized variables

%#begin loop
for i=...
    ...
    ... %# some computations here

    save('filename','A','-append') %# this just replaces the variables in the .mat file with their current values
end
%# end loop
```

You will have to save the entire variable to the file, i.e., you can't do

```
save('filename','A(i)','-append')
```

You can also do this every `n`th iteration, instead of every iteration. If you're dealing with very large datasets and only one element changes at a time, then I'd recommend only doing it every `n` iterations, or even better, writing your own binary file.

Comment: @yoda: I knew about the `save` command, however I was hesitant to use it inside the loop as it would further increase my time of iterations. Further, I am storing my `best_obj_fun` in matrix and I only want the value at the time of the last iteration for `k_to_perturb_annealing_best`.

Comment: What size matrices are you dealing with? While saving at each iteration will have an effect on the speed, it will be _noticeable_ only for larger array sizes. On my machine, saving a `100x100` matrix takes on an average `0.002` seconds. You can also move the save command for `k_to_perturb_annealing_best` outside the loop, as you're only interested in the value at the final iteration.

Comment: Yoda: I could have moved outside the loop, but that's the point I am making about stopping the program in the middle of iterations. If the code gets stopped in between then it wont reach `k_to_perturb_annealing_best` if I save it outside the loop. BTW, `k_to_perturb_annealing_best` is `200x200` matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you only needed `best_obj_fun` for each loop and you only cared about `k_to_perturb...` when it is fully finished. So a `200x200` matrix takes on the average 0.004 seconds to save on my machine. The question is, is that difference noticeable? Perhaps you could try using the profiler to see how much time the `save` command takes up in your code.

Comment: Another option, is that if you're breaking with `Ctrl-C`, and you return to the MATLAB workspace (i.e., code doesn't hang and you don't have to restart), I'd suggest just saving it then. In order to save you some typing, you can separate the two blocks of code using [code cells](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-259.html) (using %%), and run the code cell with the iteration first and when you break out of it, run the next cell, which will be the save command. This way, you're not unnecessarily saving each step and you can still save the results of the last iteration.

Comment: The drawback of this is that you don't control at what point the variables are when you're saving... for e.g., you could be in the top few lines and some of the variables might be in iteration `k+1`, whereas the rest might still have values from iteration `k`, because the evaluation hadn't gotten that far yet.